# Can you change the color/appearance of the line marker in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, line

Notepad++ lets you place a small round bullet on the left margin to mark lines.  However, with my current theme the background is dark gray and the bullet/marker is dark blue.  I can see it, but I'd prefer it be a much brighter color so that it really stands out.

Is there any way to change the appearance of this marker without changing my overall theme?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the question exactly, but I found some information that solves the issue for me.  See, the reason I wanted to change the appearance of the line bookmark (which I previously referred to as 'line marker'), is so that I could quickly scroll through the code and see the bookmark easily as it went by.

However, I have discovered that by pressing F2, you can quickly jump from bookmark to bookmark, thus defeating the need to scroll from one to the other altogether.  I realize, again, this doesn't answer the question as to how to change the bookmark's appearance, but for all intensive purposes this information provided me with what I needed, so I decided to post it as an answer here in case it could help anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

I found that color is defined in %APPDATA%\notepad++\plugins\NppPlugin_ChangeMarker.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu > Plugins  > Plugins Admin and type Bookmarks, select a plugin named Bookmarks@Dook and install. Go to Menu > Plugins  > Bookmarks@Dook > Options and pick your desired color (background/foreground) and even shape of your marker.